# Dash plotly / CSS. Font color of selected option in the dropdown menu

Tags: css, plotly-dash

I would appreciate if someone can help me.

I can change the font color of menu by:
`style={'color': '#C0C0C0', 'font-family': 'Arial'}`
but when I select the option from the menu the font color changes to the BLUE.

I have tried:
`style={'font-color': '#C0C0C0'}`
and:
`style={'font-color': 'black'}`
but still when I select the option it appears as BLUE in the menu.

**here is the screenshot:**
[image: here is the screenshot]

Looking forward for your help.
Thank you.

Comment: Did I understand correctly: the label "France" should not appear in blue but in gray? (`#C0C0C0`). The background is fine as it is?

Comment: @bk_  Hi, Yes. the back ground is ok. but the label "France" should not appear in blue.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify the CSS directly to change the styling of selected options. If you have never done this before it is straightforward- create an assets folder under the root of your project and create a .css file in that assets directory (name shouldn't matter). Enter the code below (and modify it as you want) and then save it- your Dash app should dynamically reload the .css file when you save it so you can play around with options and see what works.

```
.Select--multi > .Select-control .Select-value, .Select-placeholder {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #C0C0C0;
    
}
```

here is an example running my own dash app:

the default view

[image: before]

with the css

[image]